# Why won't imploding Post work?

Tags: php, ajax, string, post, implode

I tried

JAVASCRIPT

```
str_objects = "some multiline text";

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "127.0.0.1/index.php", false); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("str_objects="+encodeURIComponent(str_objects));
```

PHP

```
$str_map = $_POST["str_objects"];

file_put_contents("map.txt", $str_map );
```

and :

JAVASCRIPT

```
str_objects = "some multiline text";

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xmlhttp.open("POST", "127.0.0.1/index.php", false); 

 xmlhttp.send(str_objects);
```

PHP

```
$str_map = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents("map.txt", $str_map );
```

The output file "map.txt" remains empty in both cases.

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you expecting to happen? What is happening?

Comment: echo $str_map is supposed to echo the multiline text from the JS variable str_objects

Comment: use developer tools in chrome, go to networks.. re do things, and check if you're really passing a variable..

Comment: $_POST might not be an array, or may be empty. so implode wouldn't return what you are expecting. the answer is to test that a variable has the value or is of the type you are expecting before you use it, rather than assuming that it has a specific value or type or indeed is even set.

Answer (score 2):

you're not passing any post variables so $_POST is empty?

Try the following:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

More info:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: But I am passing the variable str_objects, I thought the Array Post would contain the lines from my multiline text

Comment: Maybe it would be good to help the OP with their specific problem.

Comment: @Tim how does my answer not address the problem? they haven't set headers for the POST request

Comment: It does, definitely. I am guessing the OP is a beginner, and it might not be clear to them HOW to apply this to their problem, since you don't explain what any of it does. And the code itself doesn't directly solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST data has a specific format. You give variable names and their content.

you can replace your last line in your javascript with:

```
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("str_objects="+encodeURIComponent(str_obejects));
```

then you should get the data in your PHP script.

In the first line we are telling it to send a header with the data that tells the server it is urlencoded key value pairs. Otherwise the server won't know how to interpret it.

In the send line we send the data itself, using the function `encodeURIComponent` to properly encode the content for transmission, giving it the name `str_objects`.

On the php side your data will be stored in `$_POST["str_objects"]`

Answer (score 0):

You are posting raw data, not urlencoded or multipart form data, thus `$_POST` will not be populated.

You can:

- Change the JavaScript part to send urlencoded or multipart data
- Use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the raw data

The latter is probably preferable in your situation.